# When 'Run As' from Eclipse my developed Android App, launcher Icon doesn't show up

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, manifest, android-launcher

I have looked all over the net, and couldn't find why my Icon isn't show up on my Android wallpaper (neither on a virtual device). The App starts and runs just fine when starting, but when I stop it (hitting the 'Back' or 'Home'buttons), I cannot find the icon that starts it by itself. 
My Manifest is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.maasrot.boaz"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.maasrot.boaz.splashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.maasrot.boaz.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.maasrot.boaz.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.maasrot.boaz.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>   
</manifest>
```

Any idea why ? I do have the MAIN and LAUNCHER, as all other posts say.
Thanks!

Comment: can u post complete manifest?

Comment: Is it in your list of installed apps? Did you create a launcher shortcut?

Comment: I gues no, what is the launcher shortcut ?

Comment: Just posted the full Manifest

Comment: I can see the App in "Applications" --> "Manage Applications", but not in the home screen (where all the other Apps). So , I cannot launch it independently (without Eclipse).

Comment: Your app's icon isn't going to be created on the home screen automatically. Long-press on your home screen, and see if it's in the list of apps there.

Comment: OK, I can see it in a folder call "Recently downloaded applications", when I long click the screen. Now, how can I get it into my screen, such as every normal App ?

Comment: Have you tried it on another devices/brand? I'm not sure but it could be device-specific issue; there is no "Recently downloaded applications" in Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the correct `ic_launcher` is put in all the `drawable` folders. Another thing that you can do is check if you have many `MainActivity`'s installed in your device. I guess one of those apps is your desired app and hence you would know which is the `launcher` icon.

Comment: Yes, It is the correct one; it doesn't create the launch icon even for the default ic_launcher icon. Not even if I just create a 'Hello World" App.

Answer (score 0):

> "but when I stop it (hitting the 'Back' or 'Home' buttons), I cannot find the icon that starts it by itself."

Are you sure you are looking in the "All Apps" section of the device and not on the Home screen?  The only reason I say that is because of what you said here.  The icon does not get placed on the home screen.  I would also take a look at the Application Manager in Settings to see if it got installed.

Comment: It show that it got installed, and I even have the option to uninstall it, so, it is in the device. just cannot launch it from the phone. onlt when 'Run As' Android Application from Eclipse.